# How do I convert a string into a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector, ifstream

I have a "maze.txt" file which contains several ASCII characters which represent spaces in a maze like so:

```
######
Sa#hln
#bdp##
##e#ko
#gfij#
######
```

I used ifstream to read my .txt file and defined a string to represent its contents as so:

```
vector<char> vec;
...

int main() {
 string s;
 ifstream mazefile("maze.txt");
 while (getline(mazefile, s)) {
     mazevec.push_back(s);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Above I defined a vector called `vec` in which I wish to place the contents of `s` in. Looking online, I saw many posts that suggested the use of `push_back` which is why I have it there, but my IDE is complaining that my parameters do not match an appropriate call of push_back.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring `vec` as a `vector<char>`. You want to declare it as a `vector<string>` because that is what you are adding to it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Is there any way that I could make `vec` a vector of char's though? Since `getline` only works with a string.

Comment: Why do you want to store a vector of char? Do you actually want to store a nested vector of chars?

Comment: You don't need to make `vec` a vector of chars. You can just use `std::string::c_str()` to get the raw C-style string

Comment: @TaoP.R. I'd like it as a vector of chars because the function I am building takes a multidimensional vector of chars as its input. Would it make better sense to do this with strings?

Comment: @Levi I would like my output to be multidimensional though, and I can't do that with a string. I want to store each character in my string in an individual spot in perhaps an array or a vector so that I can access each one via something like `vec[1][0]`

Comment: @cursayer: You can do that with a string. `std::string` has overloaded the `[]` operator. So you can use `vec[1][0]`. You are using `std::string` aren't you?

Comment: @Levi, yeah, thank you. I was just unaware you could do that with strings. Sorry about that, I'm diving into C++ without much prior knowledge. Cheers!

Comment: @Levi Hey again, I got it working but I'm not able to replicate the results you're saying. Looking at my maze.txt in my original post, I wanted to produce the character at the [0][1] location which in this case is S. But instead, I got `######`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot. I was getting my y and x confused and accidentally put it inside my for loop. Thanks for all your help :)